# Compatibility issue between svn-multi and lineno

Tags: line-numbering, svn-multi

There is an issue between svn-multi and lineno. Setting the `svnid` confuses `lineno` witch results in a unwanted outcome. Without `\svnid{$Id: abc.tex 1 2013-06-25 15:30:32Z asb $}` everything works as expected.

### **Edit 1:**

The wrong line numbers show up only in the paragraph before the `svnid`-command. Since in my case, I use the `svn`-command at the beginning of files that I include via `\input` that always start a new paragraph, I can solve the problem via using `\par` before the `svnid`-command. Nonetheless I am still interested in better solution.

### Output

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{svn-multi}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1] 
% calling \par is work-around
% \par 
\svnid{$Id: abc.tex 1 2013-06-25 15:30:32Z asb $}%
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the command in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\svnid{$Id: abc.tex 1 2013-06-25 15:30:32Z asb $}%

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: If you need to use \input, the following avoids the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage[filehooks]{svn-multi}
\svnid{$Id: abc.tex 1 2013-06-25 15:30:32Z asb $}%

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\input{inc.tex}

\end{document}
```

where the contents of inc.tex is:

```
\svnid{$Id: abc.tex 1 2013-06-25 15:30:32Z asb $}%
\blindtext[1]
```

[image]

Obviously this will only work if a line break is acceptable but I guess that's generally the case when a document is split among different files.

EDIT: I just saw your EDIT 1 and I guess my solution is equivalent to that one.

Comment: That solution does not work for me. I use several files that I include via `\input{file1}` and each of the files starts with `\svnid`.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question in that case since the documentation explicitly says to use \svnid in the preamble and at the start of every source file. So putting it in the middle of a single file document isn't recommended and makes it unobvious what the problem is.

Comment: IMO that makes the question more complicated than needed (not a MWE anymore), since the described problem is equal if I use at the `\svnid` at the beginning of separate files or in the middle of document.

Comment: But it requires a different solution since \svnid is not supposed to be used in the middle of a file.

Comment: I like your edited question. It keeps the simplicity of your MWE but explains why you want \svnid in the equivalent of the middle of the file.